# ipv6 address accessible from proxy but not directly on browser

Tags: ipv6

I recently took a free vps account from vps.me they gave a dedicated ipv6 ip address, I registered a subdomain as well and assigned this ipv6 to that. I am able to access my new subdomain from ipv6proxy.net but not directly from my browser.

my subdomain name is http://just10minutes.mooo.com but can be accessed only through ipv6proxy.net

Is it possible to access this site directly from browser?

Comment: Works fine for me. Then again I have IPv6 :)

Answer (score 2):

I just checked the DNS for the IP addresses connected to that hostname:

```
$ host just10minutes.mooo.com
just10minutes.mooo.com has IPv6 address 2a02:4780:1:1::1:d17
```

Your hostname only has an IPv6 address so it is only reachable over IPv6. From my systems (which all have IPv6) I can reach your server just fine without using a proxy. People who don't have IPv6 will not be able to reach is unless they go through a proxy server that does have IPv6.

If you want people without IPv6 to be able to reach your website you will have to get an IPv4 address for your server as well. A system can (should) have both an IPv4 and IPv6 address so that everybody can reach it, whatever protocol they use.

---

PS: another way to reach your IPv6-only site from an IPv4-only system is to go to http://just10minutes.mooo.com.ipv4.sixxs.org. SixXS does a lot of good work to promote IPv6 and this uses one of their services.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have a Shared ipv4 address with dedicated Port , is it possible to use this by any chance? 31.220.49.83 -p 2211  this is what I use to login to server on my ubuntu system

Comment: No, you can't put a port number in DNS. If you run your webserver on a different port then that port has to be put into every URL (every link, you'd have to tell every user to enter the port number manually etc), which is very impractical. And many company firewalls won't allow access to that port. For all practical purposes you need to run a website on port 80 or it won't be accessible to users.

Comment: Ok NO problem, but for my testing purpose your suggestion to use SixXs.org is really helping me lot. Thanks for your time